# EditText reseting coursor text insert using two way databinding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have an `EditText` in which I'm using two-way data binding. But when I'm inserting text from my viewModel to editText using data binding, coursor position reseting to the first position. How to fix this? And I don't want to set cousor to the end every time I've changed text, because I can insert something to the middle of the editText

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content""
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@={viewModel.searchRequest}"/>
```

Comment: Setting the text causes all text to be removed and replaced with the new text, so the cursor will reset. Store the cursor position everytime it's position changes and then reset it after inserting the text.

Comment: I am using two-way databinding in a screen with lots of edittexts and I don't have this problem. I wonder what is different in your case. Are you explicitly setting text somewhere? The variable searchRequest, is it a string, a livedata<string> etc?